# how can I integrate sementic ui in rails 6 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm new at Ruby on Rails. I couldn't find any installation procedure on the internet related to how to integrate sementic Ui in rails 6 application

Answer (score 2):

1. Add `gem 'semantic-ui-sass'` to your `Gemfile`
2. Import Semantic in your SCSS file (e.g. `application.scss)` `@import "semantic-ui";`

You can also include modules `@import "semantic-ui/collections/menu";`